# button to filter JTable for checkbox is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter, rowsorter

I have a JTable fairly similar to this one.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

[image: table]

I have managed to set a normal filter on it (a search function) and it works well. I want to have a button that will immediately show only the rows where Vegetarian is checked.

Ok so now thanks to the help given by @peeskillet and @HovercraftFullOfEels, this is the solution to my problem:

```
final TableRowSorter<MovieReviewTableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<MovieReviewTableModel>(tableModel);



// custom RowFilter 
            RowFilter<MovieReviewTableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<MovieReviewTableModel, Integer>()
            {
                // include method returns true to show the row and false to not show it
                @Override
                public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends MovieReviewTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry)
                {
                    int modelRow = entry.getIdentifier(); //row index
                    boolean checked = ((Boolean)entry.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 3)).booleanValue();
                    System.out.println(checked); // to test the values coming through
                    return checked;
                }

            };

            table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

            JButton onlyFeatured = new JButton("Only show Featured");
            threeButtonPanel.add(onlyFeatured);

            onlyFeatured.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                }
            });
```

It works! Thanks so much guys, I owe you drinks or something. :D

Comment: `// ***** What goes here? *****`  Code.  As in *some* attempt, if only to convince us that you don't just expect us to finish your work for you.

Comment: Fair point, I don't have much of an attempt, but I'll edit anyway

Comment: Hey I'll accept some hints or pushes in the right direction. I don't always expect the answer because I'm doing this for uni, and that sort of thing won't help me for my next assignment and my exam. If I still don't get it (as I am still new to Java itself let alone Swing) I'll come back and ask for more hints. But it is late here in melbourne and I'm tired. I tried to find what I needed on the net and on this site (that's how I came across the oracle docs link) but it didn't quite help me. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I admit to sometimes being in a position that ***I*** should be pulled up on the same grounds.  But I think yours was a fair call in this case, and well reasoned.  Seems more than that OP deserved in any case (other than a good clip up the ear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's revisit the tutorial [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

> In addition to reordering the results, a table sorter can also specify which rows will be displayed. This is known as filtering. `TableRowSorter` implements filtering using [javax.swing.RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) objects. `RowFilter` implements several factory methods that create common kinds of filters.

Things to look at:

- `TableRowSorter`. - We know we're going to need this.
- Oh, they gave us a link to `RowFilter` docs. Let's open that up in a new browser tab.
- But first the last line *"`RowFilter` implements several factory methods that create common kinds of filters."*. We should probably look to see what those *"common kinds"* are.

RowFilter javadoc

- Static methods - `andFilter`, `dateFilter`, `notFilter`, `numberFilter`, `orFilter`, `regexFilter`. Ok, I recognize the `regexFilter` from the tutorial. But those others, just by their names alone, don't sound too promising. Maybe we should implement our own. Let's look at the rest of the javadoc

> `javax.swing.RowFilter<M,I>`
>
> Type Parameters:
>
> `M` - the type of the model; for example `PersonModel`
>
> `I` - the type of the identifier; when using `TableRowSorter` this will be `Integer`

Ok so from this we know two thing. When we create our custom `RowFilter`, we should pass a `TableModel` type as the first parameter, and type `Integer` to represent the row number.

> `RowFilter` is used to filter out entries from the model so that they are not shown in the view. For example, a `RowFilter` associated with a `JTable` might only allow rows that contain a column with a specific string. The meaning of entry depends on the component type. For example, when a filter is associated with a `JTable`, an entry corresponds to a row; when associated with a `JTree`, an entry corresponds to a node.
>
> Subclasses must override the `include` method to indicate whether the entry should be shown in the view. The `Entry` argument can be used to obtain the values in each of the columns in that entry

So based on those two paragraghs, we know the `RowFilter` is used to filter out rows we don't want in the view, and that if we create our own, we will need to override the `include` method to return whether a row should be shown or not. And also the `include` method will have an `Entry` argument, from which we can obtain details that may be o interest to us, when determining which row to not return true on. Here's the basic example (guideline) the javadoc gives us

```
RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        // do your logic here to return true or false.
    }
};
```

Cool, but what is this `RowFilter.Entry` class, and what interesting information can it provide to us? Let's look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.Entry.html).

One interesting thing we can see is the [`getModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.Entry.html#getModel--) method. From that we can get our table model. So let's finish the implementation

```
private static final int CHECKBOX_COLUMN = 4;
...
RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        int modelRow = entry.getIdentifier();
        Boolean checked = (Boolean)entry.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, CHECKBOX_COLUMN);
        return checked;
    }
};
```

Not much too it. Now all that's left is setting the filter to the sorter, as you learned from the Oracle tutorial already, using the regex filter.

Here's a fill demo code. It doesn't implement the `ActionListener` for the button press. I didn't want to do *everything* for you. You should have enough information to handle that on your own :-D Happy Learning!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TableBooleanFilterDemo {

    public TableBooleanFilterDemo() {
        JTable table = getTable();
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
        RowFilter filter = getRowFilter();
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(filter);
        table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private static final int CHECKBOX_COLUMN = 4;

    private RowFilter getRowFilter() {
        RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
                int modelRow = entry.getIdentifier();
                Boolean checked = (Boolean)entry.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, CHECKBOX_COLUMN);
                return checked;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    private JTable getTable() {
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};
        return new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TableBooleanFilterDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To be honest, I've never had to implement my own `RowFilter`, but the above is the process I pretty much go through when trying to learn something new. Took me longer to write this answer, then to learn how to do it. Gotta learn to read documentation, not just tutorials. Tutorials are a good starting point, but once you get to more complicated matters, you need to dig deeper. Same with any new technology you want to learn.

Comment: @peeskillet This is fantastic, I feel like the documentation has always been intimidating for a newbie but you put a lot of effort into explaining how to use it effectively and I have a better understanding of what I'm doing here. Though I still do have a problem, and I'll edit my op to show that.

Answer (score 2):

Your RowFilter is too simplistic, and instead you need to give it more heft, more meat. The [RowFilter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) actually has a small bit of very useful example code that could help you. For example, I used that code to help my create a *very* simplistic but workable RowFilter:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
      JComboBox<String> petCombo = new JComboBox<>(petStrings);
      String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Animal", "Male", "Delete"};
      Object[][] data = {
          {"Tweetie", petStrings[0], false, null},
          {"Sylvester", petStrings[1], true, null},
          {"Lassie", petStrings[2], false, null},
          {"Peter", petStrings[3], true, null},
          {"Arnold", petStrings[4], true, null}
      };

      final MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel(data, columnNames);
      final JTable table = new JTable(model);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(petCombo));


      final TableRowSorter<MyTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
      final RowFilter<MyTableModel,Integer> maleSexFilter = new RowFilter<MyTableModel,Integer>() {
         public boolean include(Entry<? extends MyTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            MyTableModel personModel = entry.getModel();
            boolean maleSex = ((Boolean) personModel.getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 2)).booleanValue();
           return maleSex;
          }
        };

      sorter.setRowFilter(null);
      table.setRowSorter(sorter);

      JToggleButton showMalesButton = new JToggleButton("Show Males");
      showMalesButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

         @Override
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent iEvt) {
            if (iEvt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
               System.out.println("selected!");
               sorter.setRowFilter(maleSexFilter);
            } else {
               sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            }
         }
      });

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(showMalesButton);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
   public MyTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
      super(data, columnNames);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      if (columnIndex == 2) {
         return Boolean.class;
      }
      return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
   }
}
```

The filter code is:

```
  final RowFilter<MyTableModel,Integer> maleSexFilter = new RowFilter<MyTableModel,Integer>() {
     public boolean include(Entry<? extends MyTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        MyTableModel personModel = entry.getModel();
        boolean maleSex = ((Boolean) personModel.getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 2)).booleanValue();
       return maleSex;
      }
    };
```

where all I do is get the boolean value held by the 2nd column, row determined by entry.getIdentifier(), and return that value. If true, then it is selected.

Comment: for a second I thought the boolean value may not be returning right as I miseed the `.booleanValue()` on that line, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @user3690863: please re-look at the code provided in both my answer and in the wonderful answer by peeskillet, and then compare it with your code -- do you note any difference? Our code contains very small but self-contained compilable programs that run on anyone's computer that has Java and without any modification needed, and this is what you need to create: a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- the **shortest** program possible that we can run and test, and that will reproduce your problem for us.

Comment: Ah yeah... that's a good point. I don't think I have the time to do that right now. I guess this means the problem lies elsewhere in the code, and I may be on my own. You guys gave really good answers though and I appreciate that. I'm going to have to move on to another component of this application before it needs to be submitted. So I think I'll have to come back to this on my own time, and perhaps try and get someone to sit with me at uni and look at it together. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @user3690863: you're welcome, and best of luck, but if you need to come back to this, then one way to go about creating your MCVE is to start with either peeskillet's or my code as a starting point, and then modify with your specifics until you break the program, and when that happens, that's your error and you should post it.

Comment: Ok cool, if I get the chance I'll give it a shot today. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Alright I thought I'd give it a go and while creating the MCVE I discovered I had of course already made a TableRowSorter called rowSorter for the search function. So making a new one and calling it sorter and trying to use that was stupid and was a pretty bad oversight on my part. Lesson learned. It works now, I'll update my post, thanks guys.