# The required rows not removed from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

here's my ui:
[image]

As I soon as uncheck  the checkbox "single" the following rows in the table which has room type as "Single" needs to be removed.

here's how I attempted:

```
 private void singlecheckboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

      if (!singlecheckbox.isSelected()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <roomtable.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (((DefaultTableModel)roomtable.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 1).equals("Single")) {
               ((DefaultTableModel) roomtable.getModel()).removeRow(i);

            }

        }
    }   

}
```

But the issue is only the first row is removed, not first and the second..

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this is a better case for [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). What if you uncheck the check box, how will you get the data back? See the link above for official tutorial, and also see example with [custom RowFilter with explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25950000/2587435).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the first row is removed, the `rowCount` changes...

For example, this is what's going on your loop

```
i = 0
rowCount = 2
delete Row at i
rowCount = 1;
i = 1 ... 1 > rowCount, exit...
```

Instead you could try something more like...

```
((DefaultTableModel) roomtable.getModel()).setRowCount(0);
```

I know, massive cheat...

For future reference, when deleting this from some kind list (and there's no `removeAll` or `clear` method), it might be better to use something more like...

```
while (count > 0) {
    remove first element from list...
}
```

**Updated...**

Okay, so you need to remove "certain" items...you can use a `for-loop` as the automatically changes the index value, you need more control over the index value and increment only when you need it to change, like when you want to keep the row, for example...

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)roomtable.getModel();
int row = 0;
while (row < model.getRowCount()) {
    if ((model).getValueAt(row, 1).equals("Single")) {
        model.removeRow(row);
    } else {
        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to remove only the rows with room type as "Single"

Comment: Maybe [Sorting and Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) would be more appropriate? What happens when we _uncheck_ the check box? :-P

Comment: Maybe not... re-looked at the image :-)

Comment: `you need more control over the index value and increment only when you need` == convert views index to the models

Comment: @mKorbel Since only dealing directly with model it shouldn't be required, if was I using coming the view, then yes, it would be required

Comment: @peeskillet Agreeded, had thought of that, but I'm missing over context to be sure

Comment: @MadProgrammer You have an [imposter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1206653/madprogrammer)!